# wait_event_interruptible is not returning even the condition becomes true

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am working on a device driver, where i need to use sleep. I am using `wait_event_interruptible()` for sleeping.  `wait_event_interruptible()` is not returning even condition becomes true. But when i close application with Ctrl+c, It is returning. That means it is caught signal. Why it is catching signal but not condition check ? Below is the code that i'm using in my driver.

```
/*Initialization of Wait queue*/
static DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(my_queue);

/* Here i'm waiting for value at address becomes 1 when hardware writes data */
wait_event_interruptible(my_queue, *addr);
```

Comment: Because it's a first interrupt you ever get. How do you think kernel's scheduler works? In your case perhaps you have to get HW interrupt and do something there.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the process that you have put to sleep is Process1. After the condition becomes true (1), some other process/thread needs to invoke `wake_up` on the waitqueue (`my_queue`) on which Process1 is waiting.

Then, Process1 that has went to sleep will wake up. After it has woken up, you should check for two cases immediately after your `wait_event_interruptible()` call:

- Did the condition that you were waiting for happen?
- OR, did a signal wake up Process1?

Detect which of these cases (if not both) occurred, and do the appropriate handling for them.